# Infinitives modifying nouns

Tags: grammar, infinitives

[Wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#To-infinitive) one use of *to*-infinitive verb forms as being a 'modifier of certain nouns and adjectives':

- the reason *to laugh*
- the effort *to expand*
- anxious *to get* a ticket

Some other examples:

- Don't you have work *to do*?
- Everybody needs somebody *to love*.
- Do you have anything *to drink*?

What verbs *can't* be used in this way?

For instance, this pair of sentences is similar (but not identical) in meaning and both are grammatical:

- ✔ Do you want anything else to eat?
- ✔ Do you want to eat anything else?

but the infinitive-final sentence here is not:

- ⨉ Do you want anything else to get?
- ✔ Do you want to get anything else?

Comment: _Do you have anything to drink?_ and _Do you have to drink anything?_ are grammatical but very different in meaning and (deep) structure (one uses the 'have to' semi-modal).

Comment: And in fact 'want to eat' and 'want to get' don't show noun complementation (_modification_ is not the term usually used here) but catenation with a to-infinitive. //  'Is there still something else to get?' shows that _[to] get_ is not barred on grammatical grounds, but that the slots are not totally free, because of semantic constraints. 'To get' involves a sense of requirement (and might be borderline acceptable in "Have you brought all the books in? Do you want something else to get/fetch?).

Comment: What makes you think *any* verbs can't be used in this way? The implication of Wikipedia's *modifier of **certain** (**some**) nouns and adjectives* is that there are some ***other*** nouns and adjectives that can't be used in this way, but that says nothing about restrictions on which ***verbs*** can be used.

Comment: Thank you, these points are well taken. I was struggling to think of examples with 'to get', which seems silly on reflection.

Comment: Modifier infinitivals are a special case of relative clauses. For example, in "Don't you have work [to do]?", the infinitival "to do" is an infinitival relative clause modifying "work". But infinitivals don't modify adjectives (like your "anxious" example) but they do function as complements, where they have to be licensed by the head adjective. A great many (but not all) adjectives license infinitival complements. "Anxious" is one of those that does.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe because there are so many verbs that can't be used. Like the verb *beware*, for example.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: [*we will be **wise to beware** of the call of those we have just left*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22be+wise+to+beware%22) looks syntactically identical to OP's ***anxious to get** a ticket*. But I can't begin to understand the question here, frankly.

Comment: *Do you have anything else to get? Do you have to get anything else?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, bad choice. How about the verbs *used* meaning did something customarily in the past. Or the verb *can*? Or the verb *rumour*?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: ***use [to]*** and ***can*** are two of just a handful of "degenerate" modal verbs that deviate in several ways from "standard" English verbs. But I'd never thought about ***to rumour*** until you brought it up. It took me a while to find [*He rumoured that Edward had been married before he married the Queen,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22He+rumoured+that+Edward%22), and I'm not exactly convinced that's a "valid" utterance anyway (I certainly wouldn't call it "idiomatic"). It's a strange verb that only really seems to work in passive constructions.

Answer (score 3):

Infinitival clauses can modify nouns, but they don't modify adjectives, though they do complement them.

Modifier infinitivals are a special case of relative clauses. For example, in "Don't you have work [to do]?", "to do" is an infinitival relative clause modifying "work", where the meaning is modal, as in "Don't you have work that you can/should do".

But infinitivals don't modify adjectives (like your "anxious" example) but they do function as complements to adjectives, where they have to be licensed by the head adjective. A great many (but not all) adjectives license infinitival complements. "Anxious" is one of those that does.

Comment: Why is "to get" not modifying "anxious"? It seems to me that "I am anxious to get up" is a modification of "I am anxious" in exactly the same way that "I make an effort to expand" is modifying "I make an effort".

Comment: @DJClayworth The same reason that in "I ate a sandwich" the NP *a sandwich* isn't modifying the verb *ate*. It's the complement of the verb, not its modifier.

Comment: In *I am happy to help* — what do you call *to help* in your grammar?

Comment: @TinfoilHat It's called a 'complement'.

Answer (score 3):

To address your main question,  this sentence is, in fact, grammatically correct:

> 1. Do you want anything else to get?

To see why, compare it to the obviously correct sentence you mention:

> 2. Do you want anything else to eat?

Sentence (2) is correct; it means "Do you want anything else that you could eat?" Sentence (1) is also correct; it means "Do you want anything else that you could get?"

The problem is that sentence (1), though grammatically correct, doesn't make semantic sense in most contexts. After all, if I'm offering something to you, it doesn't make sense for me to imply that you'll need to *get* it.

Comment: Why does *Do you have anything else to get?* work where *want* does not? Also, where are you getting a modal sense of *could*? If you answer the question, it would be *I want pie [to eat]* — not *I could want pie [to eat]*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat There's a general rule that infinitival relative clauses about present or future time can be paraphrased as finite ones with a modal, usually can/could/should (see Huddleston & Pullum (2002)).

Comment: I took a look at CGEL... Take it out question format to understand: *I want something else [for me] to eat* is not modal. On the other hand, *There is something else to eat* could be modal — in two different ways: 1) there is something else you can eat [instead of peas] or 2) there is something else you need to eat [you have peas left to eat before dessert].

Comment: @TinfoilHat The meaning of "I want something else to eat" is equivalent to that of the modal "I want something else that I can/should eat". Get it now?

Answer (score 0):

There are no *verbs* that are excluded from this. The definition says that the infinitive can be a 'modifier of certain nouns and adjectives', but doesn't say it applies to only certain verbs.

Not all verb+noun combinations are going to be valid, but there is going to be some noun that works for all verbs. For example, Wikipedia gives an example of using "to get" (the verb you indicated could not be used in one of your examples).

Comment: Modifier infinitivals are a special case of relative clauses. For example, in the OP's _Don't you have work [to do]?_, the infinitival "to do" is an infinitival relative clause modifying "work". But infinitivals don't _modify_ adjectives, but they do function as complements, where they have to be licensed by the head adjective. A great  many (but not all) adjectives license infinitival complements

Comment: How about modal verbs, or the verb *beware*, or the verb *used*, or the verb *rumour*? There  very clearly ***are*** verbs excluded from this.